# Any company/service which allow me to test my website (app) on iphone/ipad/android devices

Tags: iphone, android, ipad

Anyone know of a service that allow me to see the screen of ipad/iphone/android devices, upload my site and check how it works there + perform QA?

(Not exactly programming question, but it still seems to be the most appropriate place to ask among the stack exchange sites.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the simulator software?

Comment: I think it requires MAC and we have only windows pcs

Comment: @Nir, the Android emulator is part of the SDK and is [available](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for all 3 major architectures. Though for iPhone, you do require a Mac to develop and use the simulator - but if you've written your iPhone app, don't you already have that?

Comment: This site is only for programming based question. This is not a programming related question. So shouldnt be posted here. Better migrate it to suitable site on stackexchange

Comment: Parth- didnt find more suitable stackexchange for this question.

Comment: @RivieraKid - its not an app. Its website(s). I need to check them on the mobile browsers.

Comment: @Nir - Which you can do in the emulator for Android, at least...

Comment: You could say this is subjective/argumentative, you could possibly say this is not a real question (it does not have a single definitive answer).  I would say its spambait and will attract spammers to post links to their crappy website, which makes me (above all else) want to delete this.  However, StackOverflow is about [programming, programming algorithms, tools and matters unique to programming](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), so this question stays.

Answer (score 2):

[DeviceAnywhere.com](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/) provides access to devices for testing.

See [DeviceAnywhere's device list](https://www.deviceanywhere.com/test-center-device-list.html) for the list of actual devices available.

Comment: Motorola makes nearly all of our phones available on DeviceAnywhere.

Comment: deviceanywhere is expensive because its for testing on different remote networks. Since I need to test website(s) I dont care about the network. Is there a less expensive solution that fits my needs?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of companies that offer this service: we use [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/). Whilst it's no substitute for the real thing, it's useful for mobile web testing when you need to support a massive range of devices you couldn't possibly have access to. They have a variety of iPhone and Android devices on most of the major global networks available for testing.

Comment: there's perfecto, apkudo, experitest, lesspainful, deviceanywhere

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like this: http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/

Not exactly a simulator but kind of fakes it :)